# crowling string in xml fragment

Tags: php, string, simple-html-dom

this is part of my HTML:

```
<li class="tel" itemprop="telephone">

+421905343255
                        </li>
```

I am using Simple html DOM praser and i try to get telephone number

My try of PHP code:

```
$html = file_get_html('file.txt'); 
$ret = $html->find('li[itemprop="telephone"]');  


foreach ($ret as $translate) {
    $translate = $translate->innertext;
    }   
    echo "$translate";
```

Ideal result should be:

```
echo "$translate[0]";  //+421905343255
```

Comment: So, what is the current result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should store your results in **an array with a different name** than what you use to loop through the DOM nodes !

```
$ret = $html->find('li[itemprop="telephone"]');  

foreach ($ret as $translate) {
    $translateResult[] = $translate->innertext;
}   
echo "$translateResult[0]";
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bk6w-gm5d)</kbd>